# Fade in fade out related div animation

Tags: javascript, fadein, fadeout

So I have this code

```
$(function () {
 $(".one, .two, .three").click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#" + $(this).attr("class")).fadeIn().siblings('.popup').hide();
  return false;
 });
 $(".close").click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(".popup").fadeOut();
 });
});
```

But I'm not quite sure how to animate it. What I want to do is when you click a link, the div fades in (it works), but when you click the related links, I don't want the box to fade out and in again (except for the texts inside it though).

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qepk0auL/)

Thanks! x

Comment: Use a wrapper for all the popups and fade that in. Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qepk0auL/3/)

Comment: You just change `fadeOut()` instead of `hide()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this to fade properly both ways I think you need to play with the z-index:

```
$(function () {

$(".one, .two, .three").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#" + $(this).attr("class")).css('z-index', 1).fadeIn(function(){
        $(this).css('z-index', 0).siblings('.popup').hide();        
    });
    return false;
});


$(".close").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".popup").fadeOut();
});
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jankrib/0zrkhhac/)

Comment: Wow, this is actually pretty amazing! I didn't notice the bug on the other one until now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works for you

$(function () {

```
$(".one, .two, .three").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#" + $(this).attr("class")).fadeIn(function(){
        $(this).siblings('.popup').hide();        
    });
    return false;
});


$(".close").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".popup").fadeOut();
});
```

});

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qepk0auL/4/)

Comment: Whoa. Thank you! It's perfect. :D